# Firebug JS warning to jQuery 1.4.2 "The 'charCode' property of a keyup event should not be used. The value is meaningless." To ignore it?

Tags: jquery, firebug, keypress, keydown

Firebug 1.5.4 JavaScript warning : **The 'charCode' property of a`keyup`event should not be used. The value is meaningless.** To ignore it? Is there any issue?

The warning appears to jQuery 1.4.2 `keyup`and`keydown`, not on`keypress`.
I have read that on changing`event.keyCode`and`event.charCode`to`event.which`must fix it, but it does not work for me.
Full code example in http://jsfiddle.net/zTevK/2/ and in [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985753/keyboard-navigation-for-jquery-tabs)
My code uses`keyup`and does not work with`keypress`.

```
  $(document).bind('keyup', function(e){
   var key = e.which;
   if (key > 36 && key < 41) {
    if (key == 37) { changeTab(-1); }
    if (key == 38) { changeTab(-imgPerRow); }
    if (key == 39) { changeTab(+1); }
    if (key == 40) { changeTab(+imgPerRow); }
    e.preventDefault();
  ...
```

Comment: This is normal, I have no idea why FireBug spams the error log with this, but I've never seen it affect anything, maybe someone else has.

Comment: I noticed this yesterday when testing an answer I wrote.  It didn't halt my code or stop it from working, however.

Comment: I'm not seeing this error in your example.

Comment: I have the same warning while using live keyup in my firebug.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The jQuery code itself normalizes every event in `jQuery.event.fix`

```
// props includes 'charCode' - this will access it
for ( var i = this.props.length, prop; i; ) {
  prop = this.props[ --i ];
  event[ prop ] = originalEvent[ prop ];
}

// also, later in the same function

// Add which for key events
if ( !event.which && ((event.charCode || event.charCode === 0) ? event.charCode : event.keyCode) ) {
  event.which = event.charCode || event.keyCode;
}
```

One of these lines of code is going to access `charCode`, which in turn creates your warning...  You don't even need to do anything in your event handler ([illustrated on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/KfNPV/))...

The "solution" I usually end up using is just running without JS warnings (errors still show up)
[image: Turning off Warnings]

You can safely ignore this message (assuming you aren't using `charCode`, and are indeed using `which`)

Comment: Not wrong, its warning is accurate, jQuery checks the charCode property itself when deciding to use charCode or keyCode, and when normalizing its event.   The warning is safe to ignore if you are always using `e.which` though.

Comment: @Binyamin: jQuery is wrong. It shouldn't be doing anything with `charCode` for `keydown` or `keyup` events.

Answer (score 3):

This is a very common error message that comes out of mozilla code. The message comes out for every keystroke and it can lead to performance problems if you have the error console open. I've complained to mozilla about this and similar messages to no effect.
jjb

Comment: It's a useful warning. Anything that helps ease the confusion in developers' minds between the roles of `keypress` versus `keydown` and `keyup` events is a good thing in my book.

Answer (score 0):

try to change charCode -> XcharCode in source jquery-1.X.X.js and everything works OK

in the lastest version 1.4.4 there are "4" ocurrences...